# Best way to solve $A$ from $Ax=b$ when $x$ and $b$ are given

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I was about to solve this equation:

$$z_1 = Ax$$
$$z_2 = Bz_1$$
$$z_3 = Cz_3$$
$$b = Dz_3$$

where $b$ is a vector and $x$ is a vector and $A, B, C, D$ are matrices. But then I realize that $A, B, C, D$ are unknown to me. So I hade to use a simplier example.

So let's assume that we have this system of equation:

$$b = Ax$$

Where we want to find $A$. What is the best way to find $A$ if $b$ and $x$ are known vectors?

Here is two options what I have found.

- Pseudo inverse: Using numerical linear algebra
- Backpropagation: Using gradient descent
- Estimation: Using a kalman filter

So what do you recommend here for me if I want to solve $A$ or in the other case, find $DCBA$ from $b = DCBAx$

Comment: You cannot determine matrix $A$ uniquely. One of the solution for $A$ is diagonal matrix with elements $a_{ii}=\frac{b_i}{x_i}$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Yes. I know that I cannot determine matrix A. But at least I can find a similar matrix that suits the equation?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu For example. Using a kalman filter for parameter estimation?

Comment: There are multiple solutions to your problem as it is currently stated. You need to list what you need from the matrix $A$. Are you developing a function to test a piece of software? Do you need $A$ to be nonsingular, well-conditioned, etc? These are all questions that will directly impact how the answer is phrased.

Comment: @CarlChristian I don't know. I'm just looking for a regular method to solve this kind of issue.

Comment: Broyden's (quasi-Newton) method constructs an approximation of the Jacobian (or its inverse) from a similar data situation. Similar to this rank-1-update process, the BFGS method  in optimization uses rank-2 updates to get an approximation of the symmetric Hessian matrix.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu The diagonal matrix is a good idea, but it only works if $x_i \ne 0$ (unless you have $b_i=0$)

Comment: You have an underdetermined linear system of equations for the entries of $A$. You could rewrite $Ax = b$ as $Xa = b$, where $a$ is a vector containing the entries of $A$ and $X$ is a certain matrix. Then you could find a least squares solution to $Xa = b$, using your preferred method of solving least squares problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My deleted answer did not address the question as correctly observed by @Winter.

---

Given two vectors $x$ and $b$, the objective is to construct a matrix $A$ such that $$Ax=b.$$

If $x=0$, then $Ax=0$ for any $A$ and we must have $b=0$ or the problem has no solution.

If $x=b=0$, then any matrix $A$ will suffice.

If $x\not=0$, then the matrix given by $$A=\frac{1}{\|x\|^2_2}bx^T$$ satisfies
$$Ax = \frac{1}{\|x\|^2_2}bx^Tx = b.$$

There is a significant downside to this matrix $A$. It has rank 1, so it likely to break any software based on Gaussian elimination.

To make further progress we turn to the singular value decomposition and write a general matrix $A$ as
$$ A = \sum_{j=0}^m \sigma_j v_j u_j^T$$
We want to choose the singular value and the singular vectors such that $$Ax=b$$ and $A$ will not break software based on Gaussian elimination.

Again if $x=0$, then we must have $b = 0$ and $A=I$ will work.

If $x \not = 0$, then we consider $b$ as follows.

If $b = 0$, then any acceptable $A$ will be singular and it should break software based on Gaussian elimination.

If $b \not =0$, then we set $u_1 = x/\|x\|_2$ and extend $u_1$ to an orthogonal matrix $U$ using Gram-Schmidt's method. We set $v_1 = b/\|b\|_2$ and extend $v_1$ to an orthogonal matrix $V$ using Gram-Schmidt's method. Then
$$Ax =  \sum_{j=0}^m \sigma_j v_j u_j^T x = \sigma_1 v_1 u_1^Tx = \sigma_1 \frac{b}{\|b\|_2} \frac{x^Tx}{\|x\|_2}$$
It follows that we should choose $\sigma_1 = \frac{\|b\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$. We are free to choose the remaining $\sigma_j$. The choice of
$$ \sigma_j = \frac{\|b\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$$
is attractive because it ensures that the test matrix is well-conditioned. On the other hand we have the freedom to ensure that matrix $A$ is arbitrarily ill-conditioned.

Comment: @Winther Thank you for catching the glaring oversight in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated, the problem may not even have a solution. If $x_1=x_2 = \cdots =x_n = 0$, the problem only has a solution if $b_1=b_2= \cdots b_n = 0$ (in that case you can just take any matrix $A$.

In the opposite corner, if $x_i \ne 0, i= 1,\cdots, n$, you can take $A$ as a diagonal matrix with entries $a_{ii} = \frac{b_i}{x_i}$.

A general intermediate situation would correspond (after reordering) to have $x_1, \cdots , x_k \ne 0$ and $x_{k+1}= \cdots =  x_n =0$. In this scenario, the first $k$ lines of $A$ can correspond to the diagonal matrix mentioned before. The entries $a_{ij}, i \ge k, j\ge n-k$ become arbitrary (set them to zero!) and you end up with the problem of determining the entries $a_{ij}$ with $i\ge k$ and $j \leq k$. So, the missing entries satisfy
$$
\begin{cases}
a_{k+1,1}x_1 + \cdots a_{k+1,n}x_k = b_{k+1}\\
\vdots\\
a_{n,1}x_1 + \cdots a_{n,k} x_k = b_n
\end{cases}
$$

A possible choice could be setting $a_{i,1} = \frac{b_i}{x_1}, i \ge k+1$ and let the rest be zero.

This leads to the block matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}A_1 & 0\\ A_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
$$

where
$$
A_1 = \textrm{diag}(\frac{b_1}{x_1}, \cdots, \frac{b_k}{x_k})
$$

and
$$
A_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{b_{k+1}}{x_1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & &  \ddots\\
\frac{b_n}{x_1} & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If the non-zero entries of $x$ are not in the beginning of the vector, we start by computing $A_p$ such that $A_P Px = Pb$, where $Px$ has the non zero entries in the beginning. In this case the final answer would be $A = P^{-1}A_P P$.